# $or query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need find field create_date, but if create_date is not defined, then find field create_time:

```
Sources_Timings.find({
    create_date: {
        $or: [
            {
                $gte: req.body.date.starting,
                $lte: req.body.date.ending
            },
            {
                $exists: false
            }
        ]
    },
    create_time: {
        $or: [
            {
                $gte: 0,
                $lt: 86400000
            },
            {
                $exists: false
            }
        ]
    }
},
function(err, timings) {
  ...
})
```

My code don't working.

Comment: its works! thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`$or`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) is a top level operator and perform operation on an array of two or more expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions.

So you query should be some thing  like this

```
Sources_Timings.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "create_date": {
        "$gte": req.body.date.starting,
        "$lte": req.body.date.ending
      }
    },
    {
      "create_time": {
        "$gte": 0,
        "$lt": 86400000
      }
    }
  ]
})
```